# Incorrect Dataframe from spark.read.format('csv')

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following to read a csv file as dataframe in pyspark

```
DF=spark.read.format('csv').option("header", "true").load("data.csv")
```

It works perfectly for most of the files but I am getting errors on some.

expected dataframe

```
 id    name    code    remarks                 code2       code3
1001   abc     123     1. this is remark 1     12            1
                       2. this is remark 2
1002   def     234     no remarks              23            2
```

wrong dataframe

```
 id                    name    code    remarks               code2        code3
1001                   abc     123     1.this is remark 1     null         null
2.this is remark 2     12       1      null                   null         null
1002                   def     234     no remarks             23             2
```

Please note that the original data has many columns. So I want to avoid providing the custom schema. If I open the file in MS Excel it does not have this problem.

How can I fix this issue to get the expected dataframe?

Comment: This is only the display issue in actual content of the dataframe is not like this. no need to worry. check the dataframe count and it should be equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

This was the common problem everyone face when using the beeline like tools.

But the actual dataframe is not affected. you can check by df.count() == 2 and not 3.

you can try this

> select id, name, code, regexp_replace(remarks, '\\n', ""), code2,
>   code3 from ;

this will inline the data.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: I checked the count and it seems its not the same. And also when I am using JOIN on 'id' from this df with 'id' of another df its showing these extra remarks lines as 'id' value for all the rows where remarks have multiple lines